# how to fix java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList while getting values from DB

Tags: java, spring, classcastexception

I am working on spring application. I am connecting to database using HibernateDaoSupport class in spring framework.

Below is my java code:

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
//imports..
public class MyTableDAOHibernateImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements MyTableDAO{
public String getDBValues() throws DataLayerException {
        String value = "";
        Map<String, String> map = null;
        try {
            map = (HashMap<String,String>)getHibernateTemplate()
                    .find("select mt.fname,mt.lname from MyTable as mt where aid= '29983L"' ");
            System.out.println("MAP elements : " + map);
            if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
                Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                    value = (String) pair.getValue(); 
                    System.out.println("name" + value);
                }
            }
        } catch (final DataAccessException dae) {
            throw new DataLayerException(dae);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

The above code is throwing the below exception:

```
Encountered serious error building result : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayListjava.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
```

Please suggest, in my code getHibernateTemplate() is returning a `Map<String,String>` .As per my requirement i need to store the value returned from database in key,value pair using HashMap. Unable to trace the `ClassCastException`. Please advice.

Comment: map is a List...Convert this list to the map that you desire.

Comment: @Snickers3192 -  Can you please elaborate. What do you mean by map is a List? The map object I created is of type java.util.Map<String,String>.

Comment: How can I elaborate, what you call map of type Map<String,String>, is actually a List<Object[]>, which is exactly what I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getHibernateTemplate().find(...)` returns `List<?>` of objects not `Map<K,V>`

You have to change to list in your code

```
List<Object[]> rs = ( List<Object[]> ) getHibernateTemplate().find("select mt.fname,mt.lname from MyTable as mt where aid= '29983L'");
```

Comment: Thanks, so you mean from List I need to manually place the object in HashMap<String,String>

Comment: Yes, you need to convert